# Rename file using multer-ftp

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, multer

I am trying to upload a file to an ftp using multer-ftp. It successfully uploads to the ftp however I need to change the name of the file. Is there a way to do this?

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: new FTPStorage({
    basepath: '/path',
    ftp: {
      host: host,  
      secure: false,
      user: user,  
      password: pwd 
    }
  })
}).single('fileupload');

app.post('/getfiles', function (req, res, next) {
  upload(req,res, function(err){
    if(err){  
      res.send('Error uploading file - ' + err);
    }else{ 
       res.send('File is uploaded - ' + JSON.stringify(req.file)); 
    }
  })    
})
```

In req.file it has the original file name as it was uploaded. How can I get multer-ftp to upload the file using that name instead of the name it is coming out as (example format it is coming out as is 5acfbabc8430fb3d311ae365f448.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [code](https://github.com/hnrch02/multer-ftp/blob/master/index.js#L9), use `destination` option to rename the file.

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: new FTPStorage({
    basepath: '/path',
    destination: function (req, file, options, callback) {
       callback(null, path.join(options.basepath, file.originalname))
    },
    ftp: {
      host: host,  
      secure: false,
      user: user,  
      password: pwd 
    }
  })
}).single('fileupload');
```

//corrected code